# Database pool CelluloidZMQ vs Celluloid vs Thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, postgresql, activerecord, celluloid

I'm seeing some sort of weird issue which I'm trying to understand, the first part of that issue is trying to understand how is Database Pool work in Celluloid vs Celluloid/ZMQ.

Database Pool.

### 1) THREAD.

> ```
>  5.times do 
>    Thread.new do 
>       puts "#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT version();').first} --- #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_id}"
>       sleep 5
>    end
>  end
>  sleep
> ```

Notice that, I'm output(ting) the `connection id` that was used by the thread.
 O/p

```
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70115833371600 <- connection id
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70115833339020 <- connection id
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70115833290000     ...  
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70115833282580     ...
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70115833251100     ...
```

As you can see a different connection id is returned by each thread that executed the SQL statement. `SELECT version();`

Above is perfectly valid as per my assumption.

### 2) CELLULOID

> ```
> class PlainCelluloid
>   include Celluloid
>
>   def run
>     puts "#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT version();').first} --- #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_id}"
>     sleep 5
>   end
> end
>
> 5.times do 
>  Sender.new.async.run
> end
> ```

O/p

```
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70120202935840  <- connection id
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70120202902760  <- connection id
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70120186634700       ...
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70120186602720       ...
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 .."} --- 70120186570720       ...
```

Again, **as expected** each Celluloid actor resulted in a new connection id. Perfectly valid.

### 3) Celluloud/ZMQ

- The sender (a.k.a Client)

> ```
> class Sender
>   include Celluloid::ZMQ
>
>   def initialize()
>    @socket = Socket::Push.new
>    @socket.connect('ipc:///tmp/qs11')
>   end
>
>   def write
>    @socket.send('Hello')
>   nil
>   end
> end
> ```

- The Receiver(a.k.a Server)

> ```
>      class Receiver
>
>       include Celluloid::ZMQ
>       def initialize()
>         @socket = Socket::Pull.new
>           @socket.bind('ipc:///tmp/qs11')
>       end
>
>       def run
>        loop do 
>         async.handle_message @socket.read
>        end    
>      end
>
>      def handle_message(message)
>        puts "#{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT version();').first} --- #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_id}"
>        sleep 10
>        end
>     end
>
>     Receiver.new.async.run
> ```

Now, the fun part. Upon executing this.

> ```
> 5.times do 
>   Sender.new.async.write
> end
> ```

I see the following output.

```
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 ..."} --- 70299372892280  <- connection id
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 ..."} --- 70299372892280
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 ..."} --- 70299372892280
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 ..."} --- 70299372892280
{"version"=>"PostgreSQL 9.4.5 ..."} --- 70299372892280
```

All query uses the same connection id.

And this is what my question is ...

How come `Celluloid/ZMQ` uses same connection id. 
Ideally, it should be using a different for each `async` call.

Answer (score 0):

## Because one `Receiver` is serving many `Sender` instances.

Take note: `Sender` in the `Celluloid::ZMQ` example, does not handle the record itself. Many give them to one receiver. Therefore, you are seeing the connection being used exclusively by `Receiver` which is also valid behavior, as given.

If you want it to be different -- you will need a third type of actor who purely handles a single database connection in its lifetime. That'd be sort of a combination of your first two approaches and your last one.

Comment: I was assuming that `.async` would use a new connection id from pool at least that is what I see in plain celluloid example. So why does it behave differently in celluloid/zmq

Comment: What is your `ActiveRecord` configuration code, creating a connection pool?

Comment: Nope I don't have any configuration code I was planning to use ActiveRecord::Connection.. `with_connection` before I stumble upon the above issue. Which highlighted me that `async` in celluloid zmq using same connection id

Comment: Can explain the above stuff in more detail as also the fact why pure Celluloid create a new connection_id every time when called with async and Celluloid/ZMQ async doesn't